# How can I display averages etc. of CSV data in Eclipse?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, csv

I've been given some data  (max temp, min temp, rainfall etc.) and our task is to read this data in Eclipse and then analyse the data.

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;



public class assign1 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
     // declare variables
     String line; 
     
     //
     BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weatherdata.csv"));
     System.out.println("Year, Month, Temp, Rain");
     
     while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
     }
     
        
            file.close();
     }   
    
    }
```

When I run the program, the data and the headings appear fine, just as expected, in the console.

**BUT my question is,**

How do I now get display the averages etc. of the data?

Comment: do homeworks on you own!!

Answer (score 1):

Keep a sum variable for the required attributes while reading from your file (so you need 2 variables). Because you are reading line by line, split your line according to the separator in your CSV file
e.g. for comma separated values:

```
String[] values = line.split(",");
```

then add the requested values to your sum variables. `values[2]` is for the temperature, `values[3]` for rain.

You also need a counter to divide your sums and find the averages.

e.g. your code can be written as:

```
System.out.println("Year, Month, Temp, Rain");
double sumTemp = 0;
double sumRain = 0;
int counter = 0;
while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    sumTemp += values[2];
    sumRain += values[3];
    counter++;
    System.out.println(line);
}
//now print averages
double avgTemp = sumTemp/counter;
double avgRain = sumRain/counter;
System.out.println("Average: Temp: " + avgTemp);
System.out.println("Average: Rain: " + avgRain);

//do not copy paste it, first learn the basics, get confident... and then play with it,
//else you won't learn, you won't find a job
```